# What is $\sigma(F)$ with F ={{3n}: $n\in N$ } $\subset P(N)$

Tags: measure-theory

What is $\sigma(F)$ with F ={{3n}: $n\in N$ } $\subset P(N)$?
I thought about that:

$\sigma(F)$ = {$\cup_{k\in K}$  {3k}: $K\subseteq N$} $\cup$ {(N\3N) $\cup$ ($\cup_{k\in K}$ {3k}): $K\subseteq N$}

Is that maybe true? Or could $\sigma(F)$ even be equal to P(N)?

Comment: Is $\{1\} \in \sigma(F)$? Is $\{2\}\in \sigma(F)?$

Comment: Your solution is $\sigma(F) = \{\cup_{k\in K}  \{3k\}: K\subseteq \Bbb N\} \cup \{(\Bbb N\setminus 3\Bbb N) \cup (\cup_{k\in K} \{3k\}): K\subseteq N\}$  and **it is right**. 
Note, for instance, than $3 \Bbb N \in \sigma(F)$, so  $\Bbb N\setminus  3 \Bbb N \in \sigma(F)$.

Comment: Does it contain the empty set? Because I can't see that. Maybe if we consider K = empty set?

Comment: Yes. Just take $K=\emptyset$.